# Could pulling too much data cause a 400 error for a Panda dataframe? From GraphQL

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, graphql

I'm using python/pandas/a script to pull from a database, and this cell is causing me issues:

```
import pandas as pd
positions = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response)
print(f'Retrieved {positions.shape[0]} records.')
positions.head()
```

When I run it while only pulling a few records it works, but when I try to pull thousands, I get this error:

Exception: Query failed to run by returning code of 400.

Is it the size of the pull causing issues, and if so, how do I go about resolving that?

Comment: I don't think pandas is causing the error.  The error is most likely from your GraphQL endpoint.  You can break up your querying of the GraphQL to return small sets of data and concatenate into a bigger dataframe using `pd.concat`.

Comment: Thank you! Will give that a whirl